# How to fetch data from database

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, axios, wordpress-rest-api

I am building a wordpress plugin in which I have implement a widget which shows analytics chart from the wordpress data table named dummy using rest api but I am failing to do so. I am using reactjs for building plugin and axios for fetching data from database and recharts for showing analytics chart.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend, ResponsiveContainer } from 'recharts';
import axios from 'axios';


const API_URL = "http://localhost/wordpress2/wp-json/wp/v2?query=dummy"

const Dashboard = () => {
    axios.get(API_URL)
    .then(Response => {console.log(Response.data);

  }).catch(err => console.log(err));

    return (
        <div className='dashboard'   >
            <div className="card" >
                <h3>Analytics</h3>
                <ResponsiveContainer>
                    <LineChart  data={Response}>
                        <XAxis dataKey="post" />
                        <YAxis />
                        <Legend/>
                        <Tooltip />
                        <CartesianGrid stroke="#eee"   />
                        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="likes" stroke="#8884d8" />
                        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="dislikes" stroke="#82ca9d" />
                    </LineChart>
                </ResponsiveContainer>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


export default Dashboard;
```

In my wordpress dashboard plugin is working well and chart is also showing but without data it will show when apiurl problem is solved.

Comment: Hey @Jit did you really get data?? check it by console.log("data",Response)
Thanks

Comment: Hey @Jamiu Shaibu thanks for your guidance but still not getting data from database

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Jit you need to call axios inside useEffect hook like-

```
const[data,setData] = useState()
useEffect(()=>{
    const apiData = axios.get(API_URL)
        .then(Response => {
            console.log(Response.data);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

    if (apiData.length>0){
        setData(apiData);
    }
}, []);
```

try this code, if you still facing issue lemme know. I will help you more.
Thanks

Comment: you have to add a empty dependency array, otherwise you'll get a infinite loop call

Comment: Sorry but now, i edited the post.. a silly mistake.

Comment: Hey @Varun Kaklia thank you for assisting me your code helps in getting response however it's not the expected data. I expecting data like this `  
{
    post: "jiten",
    likes: 10,
    dislikes: 3,
    
  },{
    name: "jiten1",
    likes: 50,
    dislikes: 5,
    
  }`

Comment: and what you got?? can you share the result?

Comment: {"namespace":"wp\/v2","routes":{"\/wp\/v2":{"namespace":"wp\/v2","methods":["GET"],"endpoints":[{"methods":["GET"],"args":{"namespace":{"default":"wp\/v2","required":false},"context":{"default":"view","required":false}}}],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress2\/wp-json\/wp\/v2"}]}},"\/wp\/v2\/posts":{"namespace":"wp\/v2","methods":["GET","POST","GET","POST"],"endpoints":[{"methods":["GET"],"allow_batch":{"v1":true},"args":{"context":{"description":"Scope under which the request is made; determines fields present in response.","type":"string","enum": an so on......

Comment: okay now do, 
const filterData = apiData.replace("wp\/v2","").replace("\/wp\/v2","")
const jsonData = JSON.parse(filterData)
if (jsonData.length>0){
setData(jsonData)
}

Make this change and check result. Thanks

Comment: Please, use indentation. Edited your answer to make it more readable

Comment: Still not getting expected data from database. I think it because of my api url please review that URL and assist me if there is anything wrong. Or provide me a fake rest-api url which helps in fetched data from database

Comment: Check api response on postman

Answer (score 0):

so normally you have to see your data in the console beside i suggest you to do it into the [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) (see [@varun-kaklia response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74253012/10500987)) . Btw, you have to store you data somewhere in order to use it (here with your LineChart component).

What i suggest you to do is to store you data in the easiest store in react : the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import { LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend, ResponsiveContainer } from 'recharts';
    import axios from 'axios';


    const API_URL = "http://localhost/wordpress2/wp-json/wp/v2?query=dummy"

    const Dashboard = () => {
       const [data, setData] = useState(null);

       useEffect(() => {
           axios.get(API_URL)
            .then(Response => { setData(Response.data) })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
       }, []);
    
    if (!data) return <p>Loading...</p>;

    return (
        <div className='dashboard'>
            <div className="card">
                <h3>Analytics</h3>
                <ResponsiveContainer>
                <LineChart data={data}>{/* Here you use the state data */}
                    <XAxis dataKey="post" />
                    <YAxis />
                    <Legend/>
                    <Tooltip />
                    <CartesianGrid stroke="#eee"   />
                    <Line type="monotone" dataKey="likes" stroke="#8884d8" />
                    <Line type="monotone" dataKey="dislikes" stroke="#82ca9d" />
                </LineChart>
                </ResponsiveContainer>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I went through your code and found some errors in that. Try this code for calling the API

```
useEffect(() => {
       axios({
       method:'get', 
       url: 'http://localhost/wordpress2/wp-json/wp/v2?query=dummy'
       })
        .then(Response => { setData(Response.data) })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
   }, []);
```